# How to create an animation showing an array of ordered numbers with number line?

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, animated-gif, gganimate

I have an array `var1` of 94 numbers. I want them to be shown in a gif with defined interval (e.g. 0.05 seconds). If possible, I also want to add an number line. I expect to see a picture like this (animated, of course):

========================================================

COV1 = 2.34

----------|-------------------------------------> <sub>cov1</sub>

_____2.34

========================================================

I just succeeded in using the `gganimate` package for some plots but then I realized I also needed to animate something that are not plots... Maybe something related to the `animation` package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem particularly enlightening (in fact it gives me a headache to look at it), but it's animated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(x=sort(runif(94, 0, 100)))

p = ggplot(dat) +
  geom_line(data=data.frame(y=rep(c(0.90,0.905,1.095,1.1),each=2), x=rep(range(dat$x), 4)), 
            aes(x,y,group=y), size=1, colour="grey40", linetype=2) +
  geom_line(aes(x,y=1), colour="grey60", size=1.5, linetype="11") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("COV1\n", round(x,2)), x=x, y=1.05, frame=x), size=5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=min(dat$x), xend=x, y=1, yend=1, frame=x), 
               arrow=arrow(angle=90, length=unit(0.4, "cm")), size=1.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.8,1.1)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title=element_blank())

gganimate(p, filename="my_gif.gif", interval=0.05)
```

[image]